# Trying to sum number in if statement with swift

Tags: ios, swift

just start using Swift and already it's getting on my nervs.. how do I fix that? (I've read already few answer but still didn't got it to work)

```
Could not find an overload for '+' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
var currentLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = attributesToReturn[i]
var previousLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = attributesToReturn[i - 1]
var maximumSpacing = 50
var origin = CGRectGetMaxX(previousLayoutAttributes.frame)
if origin + maximumSpacing + currentLayoutAttributes.frame.size.width < self.collectionViewContentSize().width
{

}
```

The error occurred in the `if` statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a CGFloat and an int.
`origin` is a CGFloat and `maximumSpacing` is an integer.

Easiest fix would be: `var maximumSpacing: CGFloat = 50`

Comment: That worked. But what if I want to add CGFloat's with Integers? How can I manage to do that?

Comment: You can overload the + operator, or use a library like this:
https://github.com/seivan/ScalarArithmetic

Comment: Still adding floats and floats technically. But yea a conversion within the if statement would work, albeit messily. `if origin + CGFloat(maximumSpacing) + ...`